# Icons of MenuItems are filled with grey color, thus not showing the image

Tags: java, android, menuitem, bitmapfactory, navigationview

I am coding a car administration app and I encountered some problems with dynamic content creation. I made a NavigationView with a Menu to display options in a sidebar. The MenuItems should have small icons to the left. The Images are created in another context and send to a mysql database with Base64 encoding which are then decoded while refreshing the menu items.

```
String carName = obj.getString("carName");
                        String sign = obj.getString("sign");
                        String bitmap = obj.getString("bitmap");
                        MenuItem item = menu.add(0, i, 0, carName);
                        byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(bitmap, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
                        BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodeImage);
                        item.setIcon(d);
```

What I did so far is creating a new Drawable with the Base64 encoded String. Then I just want to set the Icon of the MenuItem to the created Drawable. This only produces a grey colored box to the left of the MenuItem and not the specific Image I'd like to have there.

I'm using compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 23, coding with Android Studio. I ran the Debugger and checked the Bitmaps. Android Studio can display these fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally got it working.

```
view.setItemIconTintList(null)
```

did the trick here.

whole example:

```
try {
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                    NavigationView view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                    view.setItemIconTintList(null);
                    Menu menu = view.getMenu();
                    menu.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String carName = obj.getString("carName");
                        String sign = obj.getString("sign");
                        String bitmap = obj.getString("bitmap");
                        MenuItem item = menu.add(0, i, 0, carName);
                        byte[] decodeString = Base64.decode(bitmap, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeString, 0, decodeString.length);
                        BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodeImage, 50, 50, true));
                        item.setIcon(d.getCurrent());
                        item.setIcon(item.getIcon());
                        MainActivity.super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```